# Powershell - newly created zip file path not found by external function

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script for zipping up files and I'm hitting some problems. A simplified version of my script is:

```
function MyFunction([__ComObject] $zipFile)
{
   if(test-path($zipFile.Self.Path))
   {
      "Zip path found in MyFunction: " + $zipFile.Self.Path
   }
   else
   {
     "Zip path not found in MyFunction: " + $zipFile.Self.Path
   }
   # Check path directly
   if(test-path("C:\zips\july2013.zip"))
   {
      "Direct zip path found in MyFunction: " + $zipFile.Self.Path
   }
   else
   {
     "Direct zip path not found in MyFunction: " + $zipFile.Self.Path
   }
}

$zipfilepath = "C:\zips\july2013.zip"

if(-not (test-path($zipfilepath)))
{
   set-content $zipfilepath ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
   (dir $zipfilepath).IsReadOnly = $false               
}

$shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
$zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilepath)

if( (test-path($zipPackage.Self.Path)))
{
   "Zip exists: " + $zipPackage.Self.Path
}
else
{
    "Zip does not exist: " + $zipPackage.Self.Path
}
MyFunction $zipPackage
```

If C:\zips\july2013.zip exists before I run the script or I run it by opening up powershell to debug I get ( as I expect):

```
Zip exists: C:\zips\july2013.zip
Zip path found in MyFunction: C:\zips\july2013.zip
Direct zip path found in MyFunction: C:\zips\july2013.zip
```

However if the file does not exist C:\zips\july2013.zip and I run it without opening powershell (i.e. right click "Run with powershell") I get:

```
Zip exists: C:\zips\july2013.zip
Zip path not found in MyFunction: C:\zips\july2013.zip
Direct zip path not found in MyFunction: C:\zips\july2013.zip
```

I'm new to powershell, any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Code works for me either way.

Comment: Thanks. I missed out the key code section '$zipPackage.MoveHere($file.FullName)' in my simplification just before the call to MyFunction. It meant the file was not being found as it was in use. I added some code to wait until the MoveHere function had finished and all was well!